# how to get facebook user access token using API only in c#

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am looking for a code where I can get the User access token(Not App token) from a console application where I can not have a browser, in C#. Is there any API which I can use?

Comment: You can not create user tokens without user interaction; this _has_ to happen in some sort of browser/webview.

Comment: Any suggestion to get it in a console application?